# Insert using stored procedure

Tags: sql

I want to insert a record into multiple tables at single time using a stored procedure. But if it already exists, that record could not be inserted. How can it? I need help. I have link between the tables.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblrole] 
( 
     [roleid]   [INT] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, 
     [rolename] [VARCHAR](50) NULL, 

     PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([roleid] ASC)
)
```

Comment: show table schema and what you have tried so far.

Comment: i have login table and registration table. there is user id is linked for both. i need the store the record at same time. sorry i couldnt able to paste here the schema.

Comment: Do have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal that you cannot insert a duplicate record if you have a unique primary key.
You have been talking about multiple tables, but you've schown us just one table definition.
I I've understood well your problem, you would something like this:

```
create proc insert_data 
-- params are coming here
as
if not exists(select 1 from your_target_table1 where column = @condition)
   -- your insert comes here
else
  -- do nothing or log en error in an error table or do an update
if not exists(select 1 from your_target_table2 where column = @condition)
   -- your insert comes here
else
  -- do nothing or log en error in an error table or do an update
-- and soon
```

Comment: Now I can understand. My question is, my existing table column having varchar (100) datatype. Now I want to insert in it without special characters and length should be 15 only.

Comment: you can truncate your data with the substring function, like select substring(yourcolumn, 1, 15) from yourtable